# Sending an SMS From a Background Service

Tags: android, sms, background-service

As the title says, I'm trying to send a text message from a Background Service. 
I'm not sure if the code should be inside the onHandleIntent method and if not, where should I put it? 
The application allows the user to log in, and based on the account that's logged, it invokes the background service, that should run every 2-3 minutes (still didn't do that part, I'll start the AlarmManager once I get the SMS sending to work) and check if the online database has any new messages, if it does, it fetches them and extracts what it needs. The data fetching works fine, but the message is not being sent. What am I missing? 
Thanks!

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (!connected()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Not connected");
            return;
        }
        ... // piece of code that fetches the data from an online database
            // and parses it into text message info
                for (int i = 0; i < msg.size(); i++) {
                    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("+" + num.get(i), null, msg.get(i), null, null);
                    //Thread.sleep(100);
                }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: No exceptions, I used Log.i to check if the data is fetched correctly and it seems that everything works fine, but the messages are not being sent.

Comment: Are you sure that your for loop is getting executed? And you have the SEND_SMS permission in manifest?

Comment: I have the SEND_SMS permission, the application was originally fetching the data and sending it via SMS using a button click and AsyncTask, so I am just trying to move from a button click to a background task.